# Circle with rotating radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create an animation using CSS and HTML (JavaScript if needed). But I am not sure how to do it.

[image]

I need to create a circle, and the radius axis has to be spinning inside the circle at a slow rate.

How would one do that?

Comment: [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations), [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms), [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing an SVG might be the easiest way to get the shape. Then use [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) to make the entire SVG rotate.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  to { rotate: 360deg }
}

svg {
  animation: rotate 10s linear infinite;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

svg .ring {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

svg .dot {
  fill: black;
}

svg .line {
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

svg .text {
  font-size: 10px;
  fill: purple;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle class="ring" r="49" cx="50" cy="50" />
  <circle class="dot" r="2" cx="50" cy="50" />
  <line class="line" x1="50" y1="50" x2="99" y2="50" />
  <text class="text" x="60" y="47">Radius</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

creating a `.circle` parent with four divs and giving the parent `display:grid` of
2x2.adding border top on the 4th div gives us the line and radius text is in 2nd div
pushed down with padding top.

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .circle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: solid 1px black;
        display: grid;
        align-content: center;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto;
        animation: rotate 5s infinite linear;
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }

    }

    div {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;

    }

    div:nth-child(2) {
        padding-top: 89%;
    }

    div:nth-child(4) {
        border-top: solid 2px red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
        <div></div>
        <div>Radius</div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SVG, and an AnimateTransform to rotate the line.

AnimateTransform can rotate an object *around a point*, so in this case, just start with the line at whatever angle you'd like, but anchor the rotation to the center of the circle.

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle fill='transparent' stroke='black' cx='50' cy='50' r='35' /> 
  <line stroke='red' x1='50' x2='85' y1='50' y2='50'>
    <animateTransform
       attributeName='transform'
       from='0 50 50'
       to='360 50 50'
       dur='1.5s'
       repeatCount='indefinite'
       attributeType='xml'
       type='rotate' />
  </line>
</svg>
```

No CSS or JavaScript needed.